# Get extra hard drive space from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu-12.04, gparted, disk-space

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7 (dual-boot) on my laptop. For some reasons I want some more space in my Ubuntu partition.

I have installed gParted in Ubuntu. Now is it recommended to get this required extra space from Windows 7 drive (**where my Linux is installed **) directly using gParted? Will it cause damage to my boot loader or my data on the partition from where I wish to grab some space?

Here is the link for whole partition thing.

[image]

Comment: Another consideration is to buy a cheap/small SSD which will work in conjunction with your Win7 OS. This will increase drive space, performance and extend the lifespan of your existing drive. I would go as far to research dropping a swap partition on the SSD so your Linux OS can gain similar benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be fine.  However, I recommend downloading the .ISO of gparted and booting from that.  Its the same program, however you are free from any constraints that booting from the HDD might cause.